# Ctrl+key doesn't act as expected

Tags: lyx

Something weird started to happen and I don't know how to change it back.
I'm using LyX.

Whenever I try to undo something using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> I get this: `→`; when I try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> I get this: `↕`; the Enter, Backspace and delete are also giving me symbols; any combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + "key" gives me a different symbol, many of which are Hebrew letters.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please check if you accidentally switched to another keyboard layout or if any other key is stuck.

Comment: Thanks but it's not. And nothing seems to be stuck :\

Comment: Check under Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts and make sure you're using `cua` as your bind file.

Comment: I wonder if this is the same bug as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243999/ctrlkey-doesnt-act-as-expected

Comment: @Werner Thanks! that seems to have solved the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LyX allows the user to tailor the input-experience through what is called "key bindings". Informally they are sometimes referred to as (key) shortcuts. An [excerpt from `Customization.lyx`, section **3.3. Bindings**](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/KeyboardShortcuts#BindingsExcerpt):

> Bindings are used to, well, bind a function to a key. Several prepackaged binding files are available: a CUA set of bindings (familiar as the typical set of PC and CDE set of keyboard shortcuts), an Emacs set of bindings, for those of us who follow the One True Way and refuse to lower our standards, I'm kidding here, of course! as well as specialty bindings (broadway and hollywood) and other languages (French, German, etc.).

In your case, this may have switched to something other than the default/basic `cua`.

To change the key bindings, follow Tools > Preferences... > Editing > Shortcuts and enter `cua`, or Browse for another.